# Show a color gradient in a SAS graph

Tags: graph, sas

I would like to draw a box using SAS/GRAPH with a color gradient (say going from red to green). I've found references online to a macro called `%colorscale` that apparently helps with this, but can't find the code itself. Is there a way to do this?

For example, the following draws a green box. But how can I make the color blend from one color to another?

```
data box;
   length function style color $ 8 text $ 15;
   xsys="3"; ysys="3";

   color="green";
   function="move"; x=10; y=65; output;
   function="bar";  x=30; y=95; style="solid"; output;
run;

proc ganno annotate=box;
run;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this with good results before:

http://www.datavis.ca/sasmac/colorramp.html